# jQuery post запрос отправляется лишь один раз

Tags: php, jquery, yii, post

Возникла проблема. Написал функцию, которая отправляет пост запрос по нажатию на конопки. Но срабатывает лишь один раз. В чем может быть проблема?

Пример кода:

```js
$( ".delete" ).click(function() {
        console.log(this.id);
        $.post(
            "/delete-contact",
            {team_id : this.id },
            function(){
                $.pjax.reload('#team-zone' , {timeout : false})
            }
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "delete" id="1">delete</button>
<button class = "delete" id="2">delete</button>
<button class = "delete" id="3">delete</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После перезагрузки pjax-а происходит перестроение DOM.
Скорее всего Ваш выход:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function (e) { // тело ф-и
```

Comment: Точно. Не усмотрел это. Помогло. Спасибо. С:

Comment: Не проблема, удачи)